# Why is it “ich” and not “mich” in the sentence “Er war kleiner als ich”?

Tags: grammar, accusative, comparison

Every time I think I understand accusative, I find something that pokes holes in my understanding.

Most recently, I’ve operated on the understanding that any time you have two distinct entities (e.g., in *Ich habe einen Bruder*) one of them must be accusative (in this case, *Bruder* which we see in the *-en* addition to the indefinite article).

This does not apply to *Er war kleiner als ich*, though, and I’m not sure why?

I wrote the “incorrect” version in an edit (*Er war kleiner als mich*), and someone very reputable corrected it as *ich*.

Comment: It is not surprising that you are confused by this, as the English language is also confused by “smaller than I” versus “smaller than me”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea that anytime there are two distinct entities, one of them must be accusative, is wrong.

In general, it's the **verb** that determines the cases ("the verb governs the sentence"). For example, "haben" requires an accusative object. That's why you never learn single verbs, but always complete expressions ("etwas/jemanden (Akk) haben").

Occasionally, there are even verbs that require *two* accusative objects ("jemanden (Akk) etwas (Akk) nennen"). And for the verb "sein", both the subject and the Prädikatsnomen are in the nominative ("Ich (Nom) bin sein Bruder (Nom)").

Now for a **comparison** using "als", the things or persons that are compared are always in the same case. Which cases to use depends again on the verb:

> Er (Nom) war kleiner als ich (Nom)
>
> Ich gebe lieber ihm (Dat) als ihr (Dat) das Geschenk.
>
> Ich liebe ihn (Akk) mehr als sie (Akk).

Comment: »Ich bin dein Vater …!«

Answer (score 1):

The role of *kleiner als* is comparison. It only works correctly when both cases are equal. You sort of write a bracket around the packet

> [`1st. noun + als + kleiner + 2nd. noun`]

and instert it in the sentence, according to the case it needs.

But they don't need to be both nominative, as in

> [*Er* war kleiner als *ich*].

They might be also both accusative (if applies)

> Sie fand [*ihn* kleiner als *mich*].

In both example sentences the first noun is *er*, and the second *ich*. And the pieces in brackets are of the form described above.